# Eloquent Model where clause

Tags: model, eloquent

I want to create a where clause in an eloquent model. But I'm not sure how to create this. Here you can see my current model with the view v_group_request. V_group_request should be filtered on userid. With Auth::id().

```
    namespace App;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    class V_GroupRequest extends Model
    {
        protected $table = 'v_group_request';
    }
```

I tried something like

```
return $table->where('userid', '=', Auth::id());
```

But it does not work. Is it allowed to apply a where clause in a eloquent model?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

In controller you can use

```
public function index()
{
    $items = V_GroupRequest::where('userid', '=', Auth::id())->get();
    // ... other part
}
```